# Is possible to get the logstream into a CloudWatch metric filter?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I want to create a CloudWatch metric filter so that I count the number of log entries containing the error line

```
Connection State changed to LOST
```

I have CloudWatch Log Group called "nifi-app.log" with 3 log streams (one for each EC2 instance named `i-xxxxxxxxxxx', 'i-yyyyyyyyyy', etc)

Ideally I would want to extract a metric `nifi_connection_state_lost_count` with a dimension `InstanceId` where the value is the log stream name.

From what I gather from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/ExtractBytesExample.html), it is possible to extract dimension from the log file contents themselves but I do not see any way to refer to the log stream name for example.

The log entries look like this

```
2022-03-15 09:44:47,811 INFO [Curator-ConnectionStateManager-0] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager org.apache.nifi.controller.leader.election.CuratorLeaderElectionManager$ElectionListener@3fe60bf7 Connection State changed to LOST
```

I know that I can extract fields from that log entries with `[date,level,xxx,yy,zz]` but what I need is not in the log entry itself,  it's part of the log entry metadata (the log stream name).

The log files are NiFi log files and **do NOT have the instance name, hostname, or anything like that  printed in each log line**, and I would rather not try to change the log format as it would require a restart of the NiFi cluster and I'm not even sure how to change it.

So,  **is it possible to get the log stream name as dimension for a CW metric filter in some other way?**

Comment: Have you found a way to refer to the `logStream`?

Comment: This seems like a huge limitation.